# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fee_code'

Tags: python, django

when I am running

```
python manage.py migrate
```

it gives me an error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fee_code'

I am trying to migrate my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from students.models import gr_register, Classes, gardian 

class fees_type(models.Model):
    fee_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fee_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fee_type)

class concession_type(models.Model):
    concession_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    concession_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=1)
    concession_percent = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.concession_type)

class fees_source(models.Model):
    source_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='source_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.source_name)

class class_fees(models.Model):
    class_code = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee_code = models.ForeignKey(fees_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default='fee_code')
    fees_amount = models.BigIntegerField(default=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fees_amount)

class fee(models.Model):
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))

    Gr_num = models.ForeignKey(gr_register, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     default=231)
    fee_code = models.ForeignKey(fees_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     default=1)
    fee_dues = models. BigIntegerField(default=1000)
    paid_source = models.ForeignKey(fees_source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default=1)
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default=1)
    paid = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, default=1)
    guradian_code = models.ForeignKey(gardian , on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default=1)
    due_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    paid_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.paid)
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),

path('feestype/', views.feestype, name='feestype'),
path('addfeestype/', views.addfeestype, name='addfeestype'),
path('editfeestype/<int:pk>/', views.editfeestype, name='editfeestype'),
path('deletefeestype/<int:pk>/', views.deletefeestype, 
 name='deletefeestype'),

path('concessiontype/', views.concessiontype, name='concessiontype'),
path('addconcession/', views.addconcession, name='addconcession'),
path('editconcession/<int:pk>/', views.editconcession, 
 name='editconcession'),
path('deleteconcession/<int:pk>/', views.deleteconcession, 
  name='deleteconcession'),

path('feessource/', views.feessource, name='feessource'),
path('addfeessource/', views.addfeessource, name='addfeessource'),
path('editfeessource/<int:pk>/', views.editfeessource, 
 name='editfeessource'),
path('deletefeessource/<int:pk>/', views.deletefeessource, 
 name='deletefeessource'),

path('classfees/', views.classfees, name='classfees'),
path('addclassfees/', views.addclassfees, name='addclassfees'),
path('editclassfees/<int:pk>/', views.editclassfees, 
 name='editclassfees'),
path('delclassfees/<int:pk>/', views.delclassfees, name='delclassfees'),

path('fees/', views.fees, name='fees'),
path('addfees/', views.addfees, name='addfees'),
path('editfees/<int:pk>/', views.editfees, name='editfees'),
```

Error Trace:

> Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, fees, sessions,
>   students Running migrations:   Applying fees.0001_initial...Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 323, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 364, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 234, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 117, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 245, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
>   line 124, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
>   line 112, in database_forwards
>       field,   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 433, in add_field
>       definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 161, in column_sql
>       default_value = self.effective_default(field)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 233, in effective_default
>       return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py",
>   line 937, in get_db_prep_save
>       return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 789, in get_db_prep_save
>       return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)   File
>   "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 957, in get_db_prep_value
>       value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 966, in get_prep_value
>       return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fee_code'

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fee_code'

Comment: That is the error. Which line of code is throwing that error? Can you share the full error trace?

Comment: at the end of the code i have added full error

Comment: this code running is very well in my old laptop

Comment: Which is the 15th line of manage.py?

Comment: Which is the 15th line of manage.py? sir really i dont know

Comment: You can find that out if you open the file called manage.py and find the 15th line.

Answer (score 0):

In this model

```
class class_fees(models.Model):
    class_code = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee_code = models.ForeignKey(fees_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default='fee_code')
    fees_amount = models.BigIntegerField(default=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fees_amount)
```

You are setting `default='fee_code'` on the `fee_code` foreign key field. As the error says, you can't use a string there, it expects an integer.

Comment: i have removed the fee_code in default but still it is not working

Comment: @daniyalakhtarakhtar if you already ran `makemigrations` before changing this code you will have to delete the migration file and run `makemigrations` again.